# Angular 7 - Switching between imports

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

Below is a Service I've made that should switch between the imports `en` or `de` depending on the param `lang`.

If I use `lang` as it is I just prints `this.phrases` as `{0: "d", 1: "e"}` instead of what it should be.

Is this possible?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import en from '../locale/en';
import de from '../locale/de';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TranslateService {
  phrases: any = {};

  constructor() { }

  use(lang: string) {

    this.phrases =  Object.assign({}, lang || {});
    return this.phrases;
  }
}
```

if this service was called using `this.translateService.use('en')` I'd expect it to return the content from `en` import.

if it were `this.translateService.use('de')` then I'd expect to have `de` content returned.

**../locale/de**

```
export default {
  "CONTINUE": "fortsetzen",
  "HELLO": "Halo {{value}}",
  "Email address": "E-Mail-Addresse"
}
```

I have been able to get this working by doing

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import en from '../locale/en';
import de from '../locale/de';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TranslateService {
  phrases: any = {};
  constructor() { }

  use(lang: string) {
    let locale;
    switch(lang) {
      case 'de':
        locale = de;
        break;
      default:
          locale = en;
          break;
    }
    this.phrases =  Object.assign({}, locale || {});
    return this.phrases;
  }
}
```

But I hoped there was a cleaner approach

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can use [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) to create one.

Comment: `lang || {}` will always return `lang` if it is not `null`, `undefined` or an `empty` string

Comment: This doesn't feel like the way to do localization... But it is far from certain what are in your imported components / classes/ resources?

Comment: I have added what `locale/de.ts` is

Comment: Maybe try using the [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#usage) library? It is what I used for my project and it works pretty nicely. My best advice is don't try to reinvent something unless all your options are crap.

Comment: `use(lang: string) { this.phrases =  Object.assign({}, lang || {});` where `lang` is `string`. What do you expect `Object.assign` to do other than what you get printed?